# Vue: Teleport inheritAttrs false not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-teleport

I'm trying to create a `BaseOverlay` component that basically teleports its content to a certain area of my application.  It works just fine except there's an issue when using it with `v-show`... I think because my component's root is a `Teleport` that v-show won't work because Teleport is a template.

I figured I could then use `inheritAttrs: false` and `v-bind="$attrs"` on the inner content... this throws a warning from Vue saying `Runtime directive used on component with non-element root node. The directives will not function as intended.`  It results in `v-show` not working on `MyComponent`, but `v-if` does work.

Any clues as to what I'm doing wrong?

[Example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

**App.vue**

```
<script setup>
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent.vue";
import {ref} from "vue";
  
const showOverlay = ref(false);
function onClickButton() {
  showOverlay.value = !showOverlay.value;
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="onClickButton">
    Toggle Showing
  </button>
  <div id="overlays" />
  <div>
    Hello World
  </div>
  <MyComponent v-show="showOverlay" text="Doesn't work" />
  <MyComponent v-if="showOverlay" text="Works" />
</template>
```

**BaseOverlay.vue**

```
<template>
  <Teleport to="#overlays">
    <div
      class="overlay-container"
      v-bind="$attrs"
    >
      <slot />
    </div>
  </Teleport>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "BaseOverlay",
  inheritAttrs: false,
};
</script>
```

**MyComponent.vue**

```
<template>
    <BaseOverlay>
    {{text}}
  </BaseOverlay>
</template>

<script>
import BaseOverlay from "./BaseOverlay.vue";

export default {
  name: "MyComponent",
  components: {
    BaseOverlay
  },
  props: {
    text: {
      type: String,
      default: ""
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: v-show is a directive, not a prop/attribute, so this is expected that inheritAttrs don't do anything. You need to take into account how a directive works when applying it. Here it works the way it works and can't be applied to a teleport

Comment: @EstusFlask  Okay, so there's no way to access the directive's value and apply it to the inner div using `v-show` in there?  I was looking at the [directive's hooks](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/custom-directives.html#directive-hooks), but I'm not sure I can access that in the `BaseOverlay` component.  Do you have any guidance on how to fix this (other than using `v-if`)?

Comment: I could obviously add my own prop `show` and handle it that way, but I'd rather lean on the framework's directives instead of having to add an extra prop that's basically the same thing.

Comment: I don't think that v-show can be made working as is here. v-show just adds "display: none" on root element as I remember, so if there's no root element, it won't work. So it's either custom `show` prop or your custom directive. A possible answer could explain what's wrong with v-show current implementation and how it could be extended.

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought.  I was considering making my own directive for this scenario just to test it out, so we're thinking the same thing, thanks!

Comment: After digging a little further, a custom directive won't work because Vue will always throw the warning above for any directive that's trying to do this.  It honestly seems like `Teleport` is the one to blame here... I wish it allowed me to specify the root element or at least use its composition instead of being forced to use the "component"

Comment: Yes, I stand corrected, a directive isn't applicable here because it will deal with DOM only, while this would need to transform vnodes. But here show/hide functionality clearly belongs to overlay comp itself, so v-show wasn't a good choice any way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wanted to follow-up on this.  I started running into a lot of other issues with `Teleport`, like the inability to use it as a root element in a component (like a Dialog component because I want to teleport all dialogs to a certain area of the application), and some other strange issues with `KeepAlive`.

I ended up rolling my own WebComponent and using that instead.  I have an `OverlayManager` WebComponent that is used within the `BaseOverlay` component, and every time a `BaseOverlay` is mounted, it adds itself to the `OverlayManager`.

[Example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

**OverlayManager.js**

```
export class OverlayManager extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.classList.add("absolute", "top-100", "left-0")
    document.body.appendChild(this);
  }
  
  add(element) {
    this.appendChild(element);
  }
  
  remove(element) {
    this.removeChild(element);
  }
}

customElements.define("overlay-manager", OverlayManager);
```

**BaseOverlay.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="overlay-container" ref="rootEl">
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {ref, onMounted, onBeforeUnmount, inject} from "vue";

  export default {
  name: "BaseOverlay",
  setup() {
    const rootEl = ref(null);
    const OverlayManager = inject("OverlayManager");
    onMounted(() => {
      OverlayManager.add(rootEl.value);
    });
    onBeforeUnmount(() => {
      OverlayManager.remove(rootEl.value);
    });
    return {
      rootEl
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**App.vue**

```
<script setup>
import {OverlayManager} from "./OverlayManager.js";
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent.vue";
import {ref, provide} from "vue";
  
const manager = new OverlayManager();
provide("OverlayManager", manager);
  
const showOverlay = ref(false);
function onClickButton() {
  showOverlay.value = !showOverlay.value;
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="onClickButton">
    Toggle Showing
  </button>
  <div>
    Hello World
  </div>
  <MyComponent v-show="showOverlay" text="Now Works" />
  <MyComponent v-if="showOverlay" text="Works" />
</template>

<style>
  .absolute {
    position: absolute;
  }
  .top-100 {
    top: 100px;
  }
  .left-0 {
    left: 0;
  }
</style>
```

This behaves exactly how I need it, and I don't have to deal with the quirks that `Teleport` introduces, and it allows me to have a singleton that is in charge of all of my overlays.  The other benefit is that I have access to the parent of where `BaseOverlay` is initially added in the HTML (not where it's moved).  Honestly not sure if this is a good practice, but I'm chuffed at how cute this is and how well Vue integrates with it.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider moving the modal/overlay dependency out of the component and into the app composition to make it more reusable.

Note the [isMounted check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63652288/does-vue-3-teleport-only-works-to-port-outside-vue/#63665828) check - this is to add a delay if the outlet containers have not yet been defined. You may need to add additional handling if your outlets are not pressent on mount e.g. `<div id="outlet" v-if="false">`

```js
const {
  createApp,
  defineComponent,
  ref,
  onMounted
} = Vue


// 
// Modal 
// 
const MyModal = defineComponent({
  name: 'MyModal',
  props: {
    to: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    show: Boolean
  },
  setup(){
    const isMounted = ref(false);
    onMounted(()=> isMounted.value = true )
    return { isMounted }
  },
  template: `
    <teleport :to="to" v-if="isMounted">
      <div class="overlay-container" v-show="show">
        <slot />
      </div>
    </teleport>
  `
})


// 
// Component 
// 
const MyComp = defineComponent({
  name: 'MyComp',
  template: `<div>Component</div>`
})




// 
// App 
// 
const MyApp = defineComponent({
  name: 'MyApp',
  components: {
    MyModal,
    MyComp
  },
  setup() {
    const modalShow = ref(false);
    const modalOutlet = ref('#outletOne');

    const toggleModalShow = () => {
      modalShow.value = !modalShow.value
    }
    const toggleModalOutlet = () => {
      modalOutlet.value = modalOutlet.value == '#outletOne' 
        ? '#outletTwo' 
        : '#outletOne'
    }
    return {
      toggleModalShow,
      modalShow,
      toggleModalOutlet,
      modalOutlet,
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <button @click="toggleModalShow">{{ modalShow ? 'Hide' : 'Show' }} Modal</button>
      <button @click="toggleModalOutlet">Toggle Modal Outlet {{ modalOutlet }} </button>    
    </div>
 

    <MyModal :to="modalOutlet" :show="modalShow">
      <MyComp /> 
    </MyModal>

    <div id="outletOne">
      <h2>Outlet One</h2>
      <!-- outlet one -->
    </div>

    <div id="outletTwo">
      <h2>Outlet Two</h2>   
      <!-- outlet two -->
    </div>

  `
})



//
// Assemble
// 
const app = createApp(MyApp)
app.mount('body')
```

```css
/* just some styling */
#outletOne { color: tomato; }
#outletTwo { color: olive; }
h2 { margin: 0; }
[id*=outlet]{ display: inline-flex; flex-direction: column; padding: 1rem; }
button { margin: 1rem; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.1.4/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it seems that the issues I have with Teleport go a bit further.  For instance, if I want to use `KeepAlive` to wrap around my dialog, it won't work properly because it appears `KeepAlive` is expecting an actual element at the root to cache it.  I honestly don't think we can reliably use `Teleport` as the root element in a component definition, which is unfortunate because that's a pretty major use case.